# Difference between archivelog options in rman

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

What is the difference betweeen those two commands regarding archivelogs:

```
BACKUP DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG;
```

and

```
BACKUP ARCHIVELOG ALL;
```

Comment: the first one backs up the entire database plus archivelogs the 2nd only backs up the archivelogs

Answer (score 0):

BACKUP DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG;

> > > Backup entire database along with archivelogs

BACKUP ARCHIVELOG ALL;

> > > Backup archivelogs alone.